# Why is my namespace undefined?

Tags: javascript

I have a simple piece of code.  When I press a button I would like to change the color of that button.  The present error that I am getting when I press this button is 'Cannot read property 'changeColor' of undefined'.  I do not understand where I am going wrong.  I have written this code with the intention of not over polluting the global namespace  as I intend to add more code.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title> </title>
 <style>
    #wrap{
        margin-top: 30px;
        margin-left: 30px;
    }
    .btn{
        font-size: 20px;
        width: 65px;
        height: 45px;
    }

</style>

</head>

<body>
<div id="wrap">
<button id="btn1" onclick="pub.changeColor('#66FFFF')"    class="btn">btn1</button>
<button id="btn2" class="btn">btn2</button>
</div>
```

my JS file:

```
var pub = (function(){
    var changeColor = function(element, color){
    element.style.backgroundColor = color;

    }
})();
```

Comment: That is because `pub` is not an object but an IIFE. Also, even if you try to call `changeColor()` it will not work as it is a scoped variable.

Comment: `pub` doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have specific reasons to use a factory method wrapped inside of an anonymous function, I would recommend using just an object with a key defined as your function.

```
var pub = {
    changeColor: function(element, color){
        element.style.backgroundColor = color;
    }
};
```

This is much easier to read than the factory method.

Answer (score 2):

Because you don't return anything, the value of `pub`is undefined. Better:

```
var pub = (function(){
  return {
    changeColor: function(element, color) {
      element.style.backgroundColor = color;
    }
  }; 
})();
```

You can now use local variables declared inside of the IIFE, which are private to the code of the IIFE itself. The properties of the object that you are returning are what is ultimately visible to the users of your `pub` module.